# extracting command using regular expression

Tags: regex, splunk

I need to extract the command, whatever we see in ( ) after the word CMD in the following line.

```
Oct 29 08:00:01 data2 crond[14368]: (root) CMD (sh -xv /home//ste-telnet.sh > /home/hari/logs/ste-telnet$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%h_%m').succ 2> /home/hari/logs/ste-telnet$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%h_%m').err)
```

I need to use regular expression for this since splunk understands only that.

Comment: Will the command always span the entirety of the rest of the string? (Will the end of the string always be immediately after the ending `)`?)

Comment: There can be multiple ((( and ))) between the first ( after the word CMD. You can check this file on any linux machine # tail /var/log/cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CMD (.*)$
```

This will work if the last thing on the line is a command (the column containing CMD is the last column)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky. The problem is that you're having nested parentheses there. So if you use

```
CMD \((.*)\)
```

you will get a correct result in your case (the actual command will be in the match's group number 1), but that would fail as soon as you'd have more than one command (or more than one set of outermost parentheses after `CMD`) in your string.